# Given a k-sorted array, give an algorithm which runs faster than Θ(nlogn)

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you are given an k-sorted array, in which no element is farther than k positions away from its final (sorted) position.  Give an algorithm which will sort such an array.  Prove its correctness. Analyze its running time.

I realize the running time must be  Θ(nlogk) but have yet to come up with an algorithm that matches this.  I've thought about mergesort but the dividing step leads to O(logn).  Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

One approach might be to take any priority queue with logarithmic bounds (with regard to the size of the queue), and go over the array, inserting elements of the array into the queue, and popping the minimums from the queue into the array.

If done correctly, then this approach would indeed sort the array (the point is to pop the minimum only when you are sure the appropriate element is already in the queue) and the size of the queue would be $O(k)$ (to ensure $O(n \log k)$ time).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I'm thinking a heap would be the best implementation for the queue.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you sort the left half of the array and sort the right half of the array, then you only need to do a merge of the two sorted lists of $k$ elements around the middle to potentially put them in the right order. This takes $O(k)$ extra time. So your recursion for running time using this strategy is $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(k)$ where the base case is $T(k) = O(k \log k)$. This should solve to $T(n) = O(n \log k)$.

Comment: Since both halves are sorted, you need only _merge_ the $k$ last from the first half with the $k$ first from the second half, so it's only an extra $O(k)$.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll update the recursion. =) Thankfully it doesn't change the overall run-time

Comment: Wouldn't the sorting of the two halves contribute to the running time as well?